# Kendo Grid with pivoted dynamic columns

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to get to generate a Kendo Grid with dynamically generated columns using Angular. However, I want to match the right ticker symbol corresponding with the column. Here is my code:

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of tickerColumns" field="quantity" title="{{column.ticker}}">
<ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
    <input *ngIf="dataItem.ticker == column.ticker"
           [(ngModel)]="dataItem.quantity"
           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="k-textbox" required />
</ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

The `tickerColumns` array is simply an array that contains the three ticker symbols. The main data structure looks like this:

[image]

However, the result isn't what I expected, as if the ngIf clause isn't acting as it should.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the `data` and `tickerColums` as json text in your question body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue using a little help from the folks at Telerik, they've instructed me to use the `kendoGridCellTemplate` instead of the `kendoGridEditTemplate` directive. But doing this, the cells will always be editable even if you are not editing the line. You have to have a `isEditing` property in your view model (which I already had) and use this boolean value to enable or disable the text-box containing the values like so:

**HTML**

```
    <kendo-grid-column field="quantity" title="{{column.ticker}}" *ngFor="let column of tickerColumns;">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
          <input *ngIf="dataItem.ticker == column.ticker"
                 [disabled]="!dataItem.isEditing"
                 [(ngModel)]="dataItem.quantity"
                 [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="k-textbox" required />
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

When in edit mode (that is when you click the edit button next to a single line) just toggle the isEditing value for that dataItem. When you cancel or save and end editing, toggle it again. You now have a custom pivot grid for Kendo Angular:

[image]